# Amazon S3 Images

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm attempting to build a Rails application that uses Amazons S3 service. I'm able to upload images to my bucket but when I try to display them in a browser window my image is downloaded to my computer instead of being shown in the browser which is what I want.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/skateparks/b_72e3d8d31fc4263f40b6.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Content-Type header when you upload the image to S3.

Comment: More specifically, set "Content-Type" to "image/png" in the case of the image you are referencing.